# Not able to read data from excel in SOAPUI groovy

Tags: groovy, soapui

I am new to SOAPUI groovy and trying to read data from excel by using .jxl but I am facing a problem. 
Code is throwing an error for "wb" at line mentioned in code: "value1 = wb.getSheet(0).getCell(0, RowSelector).getContents(); //cell A1". 
Error message: "groovy.lang.missingpropertyexception. No such property.wb for class". 
Please help where I am doing wrong.

I have already added.jxl(2.6.10) and poi(3.11) jar in soapui/bin/ext.soap version is 4.5

```
import jxl. * ;
import jxl.write. *;
def value1;
def value2;
def value3;
//pull value from test suite properties
def RowSelector =         
 testRunner.testCase.testSuite.getPropertyValue("RowSelector");
//Read Excel

Workbook workbook = Workbook.getWorkbook(new     
File("C:\\Users\\abc\\Desktop\\Data\\Misc\\soapUI- 
4.5.0\\bin\\Excel\\Temp.xls"));
//creating a copy to save results in
WritableWorkbook copy = Workbook.createWorkbook(new 
File("C:\\Users\\abc\\Desktop\\Data\\Misc\\soapUI- 
4.5.0\\bin\\Excel\\Results\\Output.xls"), workbook);

File datasheet = new 
File("C:\\Users\\abc\\Desktop\\Data\\Misc\\soapUI- 
4.5.0\\bin\\ResultTemp.xls");
if (datasheet.exists()) {
log.info("Exist");
}
else {
log.info("Blank");
}
// loading Values from Excel (A1) to TestSuite properties
ERROR COMES IN BELOW LINE ON WB
value1 = wb.getSheet(0).getCell(0, RowSelector).getContents(); //cell 
A1
testRunner.testCase.testSuite.setPropertyValue("TestSuitevalue1", 
value1);
log.info("Value1 Is: " + value1);
```

Comment: When i comment this "value1 = wb.getSheet(0).getCell(0, RowSelector).getContents(); //cell 
A1" line then i get the value as a null....don't what's wrong with it!

Answer (score 0):

My advice would be to use Fillo Jar -
[https://codoid.com/fillo/][1]
You need to keep jar in ext folder and then use java code to connect to xls, I did same in my previous project.